# Is adding Webpack to finished project (React.js) a good practice?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm starting journey with React and have a very important question for me : as I'm not familiar with Webpack can I add it later - after I finish my project? Won't it cause any problems in file structure and so on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add webpack once your project is complete, but this isn't really good practice.

Webpack allows you to work in ways which would not be possible without such a tool. Webpack does lots of things, but most of the things which it does are useful when you're developing code, not once you're done developing. If you were to do add webpack once you've finished your project, you would have set up your code in a way which doesn't take advantage of webpack.

For React, webpack makes it easy to split your components into multiple files, and it allows you to transform files containing jsx.

Webpack can be a pain to configure, but there are options to make your life easier, like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Alternatively, [parcel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel) has a lot of the functionality of webpack, without the config.